# VirtoCommerce - localization questions

Tags: localization, virtocommerce

I'm trying to localize my demo store which has installed on my dev enviroment. Could you help me with some questions please?

1. What should I keep in mind for localize static content (labels, etc.)? Is it enough to store localized values to [dbo].[Localization] table?
2. Is there any other way then Commerce Mаnаger to localize dynamic content (categories, items, etc)? Could you provide some details how localized values are stored in DB?
3. How can I change initial locale (en-us) to smthg different? Is there any Default Language Setting available for whole site?

Thanks in advance,
Mikhail Solyakov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. All static content is saved in Localization table. So all labels for frontend are localized there.
2. For categories, items the localized content is stored in properties (with multi laguage attribute set to true). The languages are determined on what languages are select for the catalog. You can also pick default language for the catalog.
3. Default language can be specified for the store in store details.

PS: we changing how localization is done for the 2.0 version. Especially related to how frontend is localized (it is now accomplished through theme locale json files). You can find more details in webadmin branch on github.